# É correto usar JSON para armazenar dados que não precisam estar em base de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, json

Ex: Na empresa onde eu trabalho colocaram no meu código um grande quantidade de dados que não precisam estar no banco de dados, mas não são textos ou conteúdo de fato. São um monte de validações e dependendo da cláusula ele retorna um certo tipo de conteúdo, o problema é que tudo está no mesmo arquivo, o que atrapalha muito na leitura de código, geralmente nesses casos eu gosto de deixar os dados em um arquivo JSON e pegar só o necessário deixando o código fonte mais enxuto.

Esta prática é correta? O que seria melhor?

Comment: Se poderes dar um exemplo seria melhor. Mas ter dados estáticos num JSON é boa prática sim e estando em memória (numa variável) é rápido de consultar.

Comment: @mikaellemos033 Só isto? Tem alguma coisa a ver com JSON?

Comment: Recentemente adicionaram um trecho de código assim no meu arquivo: 

 if( $x = 'x') { 
  $x = 'teste';
  $y = 'yteste';
 }elseif($x = 'w'){
  $x = 'teste2';
  $y = 'zteste'; 
 } ....

o que eu costumo fazer é pegar esses dados jogar em um JSON, e depois eu simplesmente pego os dados eu faço um filtro.

Comment: @bigown sim tem a ver com JSON, pois minha dúvida é se essa prática é correta, e se posteriormente isso poderia acarretar em algum problema.

Comment: Agora você colocou um trecho maior de código mas ainda não consigo ver a dificuldade em fazer isto com JSON. Se não fosse JSON provavelmente seria outra coisa que estará sendo manipulada ali. Não sei se faria grande diferença. Mas pode ser. Tá faltando contexto. De qq forma dei uma resposta genérica. Melhoro se tiver algo mais específica.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

É difícil dizer sem ver o caso concreto, abstratamente não tem nada de errado, inclusive hoje todos os arquivos de configuração de aplicações modernas usam este formato. Antes usava-se o famoso formato `ini`, ou XML, ou ainda formatos proprietários.

Não deve ser o seu caso mas já há muita gente trocando dados em formato JSON.

Precisaria descobrir porque está difícil de ler e se há algo que pode ser feito para mudar isto. Mas duvido que o problema seja o JSON.

Particularmente eu prefiro formas mais estruturadas de guardar certas informações, quando possível, então prefiro deixar em memória em um *array* ou outra estrutura de dados adequada ou mesmo em tabelas no banco de dados.

Mesmo que isto esteja no código e já esteja em memória, eu jogaria os dados para uma estrutura de dados e evitaria ficar acesso a *string* do JSON toda hora.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Poder pode, creio que não existam práticas certas ou erradas, depende muito do que você precisa.

Mas a questão é se você vai precisar consultar isso toda hora do arquivo. Ler o arquivo toda hora pode causar lentidão desnecessária.

O interessante é fazer como o colega Sérgio citou no comentário. Importa esses dados para a memória (deixando na sessão para web ou estática na aplicação).

Assim a leitura não ficará lenta, ainda mais se você precisar toda hora.